# Why can't convert a tuple to a int in python?

Tags: python

My python code is changing a random generated number to `int`, but then the array thinks it's a `tuple`. I have no idea why.

```
import random

board_state = []
width = 5
height = 5

def dead_state():
    for i in range(0, height):
        board_row = []
        for j in range(0, width):
            board_row.append(0)
        board_state.append(board_row)

def random_state():
    dead_state()
    interator = int(round(random.random() * 5) + 3)
    for i in range(0, interator):
        width_Select_Test = round(random.random() * width)
        height_Select_Test = round(random.random() * height)
        width_Select_Test = int(width_Select_Test)
        height_Select_Test = int(height_Select_Test)
        print(type(width_Select_Test))
        print(type(height_Select_Test))

        board_state[height_Select_Test, width_Select_Test] = 1

random_state()
print(board_state)
```

The print statements after the conversion says its an int, but then throws an error in the array, saying that it is a tuple.

Comment: In `board_state[height_Select_Test, width_Select_Test] = 1`, the `height_Select_Test, width_Select_Test` is interpreted as a tuple

Comment: `b[x,y]` is not equivalent to `b[x][y]`.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is correct:

```
...
board_state[height_Select_Test, width_Select_Test] = 1
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

What is the 'tuple' here? The *combined* value `height_Select_Test, width_Select_Test`!

Other than in other languages (then again equivalent to, erm, yet other languages), in Python you do not use a comma to indicate 2D arrays. You must use double indexing:

```
board_state[height_Select_Test][width_Select_Test]
```

since each list of `board_state` is a sub-list in its own.

Comment: Specifically, Python doesn't *have* two-dimensional lists; you *nest* one-dimensional lists to *simulate* two-dimensional data structures.

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: Instead of `board_state[height_Select_Test, width_Select_Test]` you should access it with `board_state[height_Select_Test][width_Select_Test]`.

**Why**? Reason: In Numpy, we can index a high-dimensional array with arr[x,y...z] depending on the number of dimension it has. However, `board_state` in this case is a list of list. You still have to index the integer element properly by first accessing the `i_th` list within this list of lists and then the `j_th` element within the `i_th` list. Hence, only `arr[i][j]` works, and not `arr[i, j]` which is typically supported in **numpy** or other deep learning frameworks. (story for another day)

Comment: Pointing out NumPy arrays as an example of a multidimensional data structure is useful.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you **need** to use `[x][y]` rather than `[x, y]`,
the are **not** equal.

Your code will still fail, because the random numbers you generate can be higher than the length of your list. Thus I added the `-1` to correct that offset.

For better code, do not use `range(0, variable)`, it is equal to `range(variable)`.

Improved, functional code:

```
import random

board_state = []
width = 5
height = 5

def dead_state():
    for i in range(height):
        board_row = []
        for j in range(width):
            board_row.append(0)
        board_state.append(board_row)

def random_state():
    dead_state()
    interator = int(round(random.random() * 5) + 3)
    for i in range(interator):
        width_Select_Test = round(random.random() * width)
        height_Select_Test = round(random.random() * height)
        width_Select_Test = int(width_Select_Test)
        height_Select_Test = int(height_Select_Test)

        board_state[height_Select_Test-1][width_Select_Test-1] = 1

random_state()
print(board_state)
```